# Import expired SSL certificate into Java keystore

Tags: java, ssl, jmeter

I need to be able to point JMeter at a test server which has an expired SSL certificate (it will be some time before we are able to renew it).  JMeter is quite rightly throwing an exception when it tries to connect:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:572)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:640)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:284)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1075)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1064)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:426)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:255)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Does anybody know of any way that I can import said certificate into the keystore and in the process change the expiry date (and would this even help or would the fact that the server certificate has expired still cause this exception to be thrown)?

I've tried to set the validity as part of the import but this is ignored:

```
keytool -import ... -validity 100
```

**P.S** - I know I could implement my own     TrustManager which ignores these checks but my fingers won't allow me to write such evil code and I'd much rather get to a solution that I can install on the server without having to modify JMeter!

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You cannot change the certificates expiry date on import, as this is part of the "signed" content - otherwise anybody could extend the certificates lifetime indefinitely!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JMeter does not validate certificate so this is not the cause of your issue.

Which implementation do you use, java, HC3 or HC4 ?

Your issue could come from error in Socket version negotation.
Try setting this in user.properties:

- https.socket.protocols=SSLv2Hello SSLv3 TLSv1

You may have to play with them depending on your server configuration, for example only set this:

- https.socket.protocols=SSLv3

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It looks like the validation is happening at the JRE (sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl) level so I'm pretty sure it's a security check around the certificate expiry dates (we're able to get JMeter working over https to other servers).

Comment: Which implementation do you use ? Show the full stacktrace you get.

Comment: JMeter 2.8 - I've added the full stacktrace to the original post.

Comment: You are right neither JMeter nor the underlying connection mechanism cares about expiry dates of certificates - this was a red herring.  My problem lied around a re-direct that was sending me to a non https port.  Thanks for your input :)